# Rules for word ranking in sentences

Tags: nlp

I am looking for research and algorithms on classifying document importance based on the location of a searched keyword in the sentence. I remember seeing interesting papers on this topic before, but now that I need those I cannot find the good ones.

Can you please point me to recent or classic works in sentence relevance to a query?

Thank you very much!

Evgeniy

Answer (score 0):

Some google search terms that might help you : sentence retrieval, query type identification, query expansion, type-based query expansion, relevance feedback.